# apache server hit differs from database counts

Tags: php, mysql, apache

To manage a click server I am using apache as my http server and mysql database server.The concept is when user hits our server we enter the detail in our database. But while checking the access log of apache I found that there is mismatch between apache hits and mysql entries.

Eample: in apache there is hit per minute is around 3000 but in mysql the entry count is 2500.

So, kindly guide me that where I am lacking. Feel free to ask me any information regarding the issue. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I'd start by looking at what the 500 records that aren't being logged have in common.

Comment: Sure... I love trying to figure out vaguely worded requirements for a system I'm not being paid to develop. Besides which, it sounds vaguely illegal to be harvesting IP's like that.